# Detectar tokens de identificadores y saltos de línea con expresiones regulares

Tags: java, regex

El problema es el siguiente: Usando REGEX en java necesito leer un archivo de entrada el cual contiene un código, este código debe ser analizado e identificar cada token.

El problema surge cuando uso REGEX y me detecta `"if_simple"` como palabra reservada. El problema son mis expresiones regulares la cual me gustaría me ayudaran a solucionar:

Para palabras reservadas, estoy usando:

```
tokenizer.add("(program|var|const|begin|end|Writeln|then|else|end|Mayor|Menor)", 1, "Palabra Reservada");
```

Pero `if_simple` debería reconocerlo como "Identificador" en:

```
tokenizer.add("((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))", 2, "Identificador");
```

Obtengo los identificadores como nombres de variables o el nombre de programa pero entiendo que puede escribirse que "palabras" o caracteres omitir.
Intenté usando:

```
[^if]
```

Sin obtener resultados.
Les dejo mi código para generar tokens:

```
Tokenizer tokenizer = new Tokenizer();
tokenizer.add("(program|var|const|begin|end|Writeln|then|else|end|Mayor|Menor)", 1, "Palabra Reservada");
tokenizer.add("((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))", 2, "Identificador");
tokenizer.add("(;|,)", 3,"Puntos y Coma");
tokenizer.add("(:)",4,"Dos Puntos");
tokenizer.add("(=|<|>)",5,"Simbolos");
tokenizer.add("([0-9]+)", 6, "Numero");
tokenizer.add("(INTEGER|Integer|BOOLEAN|DOUBLE|REAL|CHAR)",7,"Tipos Datos");
tokenizer.add("(\\()", 8, "Simbolos '(' ");
tokenizer.add("(\\))", 9, "Simbolos ')' ");
tokenizer.add("(')",10,"Comillas Simples");
tokenizer.add("(\\.)",11,"Punto final");
```

Este es mi codigo completo "Test":

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Tokenizer tokenizer = new Tokenizer();
    tokenizer.add("\\b(program|var|const|begin|end|Writeln|if|then|else|end|Mayor|Menor)\\b", 1, "Palabra Reservada");
    tokenizer.add("((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))", 2, "Identificador");
    tokenizer.add("(;|,)", 3,"Puntos y Coma");
    tokenizer.add("(:)",4,"Dos Puntos");
    tokenizer.add("(=|<|>)",5,"Simbolos");
    tokenizer.add("([0-9]+)", 6, "Numero");
    tokenizer.add("(INTEGER|Integer|BOOLEAN|DOUBLE|REAL|CHAR)",7,"Tipos Datos");
    tokenizer.add("(\\()", 8, "Simbolos '(' ");
    tokenizer.add("(\\))", 9, "Simbolos ')' ");
    tokenizer.add("(')",10,"Comillas Simples");
    tokenizer.add("(\\.)",11,"Punto final"); 
    try
    {
      String content = new Scanner(new File("archivoEntrada.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
      String codigo= content;
      tokenizer.tokenize(codigo);
       String saFichero="archivoSalida.txt";
        File ficherosa = new File(saFichero);
        PrintWriter psa =new PrintWriter(ficherosa);
      for (Tokenizer.Token tok : tokenizer.getTokens())
      {
        psa.println("Token:" + tok.token + "| " + tok.sequence + "["+tok.tipo+"]");
        psa.flush();
        System.out.println("Token:" + tok.token + "| " + tok.sequence + "["+tok.tipo+"]");
      }

    }
    catch (ParserException e)
    {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) 
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
   System.err.println("Caught FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());                                                                                                                                                                                                          
   throw new RuntimeException(e);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     } 

  }
}
```

Tokenizer:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class Tokenizer
{
  private class TokenInfo
  {
    public final Pattern regex;
    public final int token;
    public final String tipo;
    public TokenInfo(Pattern regex, int token, String tipo)
    {
      super();
      this.regex = regex;
      this.token = token;
      this.tipo = tipo;
    }
  }


  public class Token
  {
    public final int token;
    public final String sequence;
    public final String tipo;
    public Token(int token, String sequence, String tipo)
    {
      super();
      this.token = token;
      this.sequence = sequence;
      this.tipo = tipo; 
    }

  }

  private LinkedList<TokenInfo> tokenInfos;
  private LinkedList<Token> tokens;

  public Tokenizer()
  {
    tokenInfos = new LinkedList<TokenInfo>();
    tokens = new LinkedList<Token>();
  }

  public void add(String regex, int token, String tipo)
  {
    tokenInfos.add(new TokenInfo(Pattern.compile("^("+regex+")"), token, tipo ));   
  }

  public void tokenize(String str)
  {
    String s = str.trim();
    tokens.clear();
    while (!s.equals(""))
    {
      boolean match = false;
      for (TokenInfo info : tokenInfos)
      {
        Matcher m = info.regex.matcher(s);
        if (m.find())
        {
          match = true;
          String tok = m.group().trim();
          s = m.replaceFirst("").trim();
          tokens.add(new Token(info.token, tok, info.tipo));
          break;
        }
      }
      if (!match) throw new ParserException("Error inesperado en: "+s);

       try{ String saFichero="archivoError.txt";
        File ficherosa = new File(saFichero);
        PrintWriter psa =new PrintWriter(ficherosa);
        psa.println("Error inesperado en: "+s );
        psa.flush();
       ;}
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) 
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
   System.err.println("Caught FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());                                                                                                                                                                                                          
   throw new RuntimeException(e);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     } 
    }
  }

  public LinkedList<Token> getTokens()
  {
    return tokens;
  }

}
```

ParserException

```
public class ParserException extends RuntimeException {
  public ParserException(String msg) {
    super(msg);
  }
}
```

El problema que también tengo es que no me detecta la entrada si no está en formato "lineal". Ejemplo:

```
program if_simple; var a:Integer; b:Integer; begin a:= 8; b:=5; if(a>b) then Writeln('mayor:',a) end.
```

Cuando debería detectarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
program if_simple; 
var 
a:Integer; b:Integer; 
begin a:= 8; b:=5; 
if(a>b) then @
Writeln('mayor:',a) 
end.
```

Comment: Si la intención es que coincida con `if`, pero que no coincida con `if_simple`, deberías usar límites de palabra completa: `"\\b(if|else|for|etc)\\b"`

Comment: Y sería bueno que incluyas qué es lo que estás haciendo en `Tokenizer.add()` para comprender cómo estás generando el regex en tu parser

Comment: @Mariano Funciona perfectamente como dices, agregué el codigo completo para que puedas observarlo. El unico problema que me queda es el citado en la parte inferior, ya que no detecta mi entrada de codigo si no esta ordenado linealmente (No se salta los saltos de pagina, solo los espacios en blanco)

Comment: entiendo, pero ¿cuál sería el token que debería coincidir con el salto de línea? No hay ninguno que hayas agregado que esté destinado a que coincida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Que coincida con palabras completas

Para el primer caso, y poder diferenciar `if` de `if_simple`, se pueden utilizar límites de palabra completa con [`\b`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bounds) (*[Boundary matchers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bounds)*). Por ejemplo, para tus palabras reservadas podríamos usar:

```
tokenizer.add("(program|var|const|begin|end|Writeln|if|then|else|end|Mayor|Menor)\\b", 1, "Palabra Reservada");
```

---

#### Devolver saltos de línea como un token

En cuanto a los saltos de línea, no hay ningún token que estés agregando que esté destinado a coincidir con éstos. Una opción sería generarlo directamente:

```
tokenizer.add("\\r?\\n", 1, "Salto de línea");
```

U otra opción sería agregar un token que coincida con cualquier espacio en blanco:

```
tokenizer.add("\\s+", 1, "Espacios en blanco");
```

- `\s` coincide con `[ \n\r\t\f]` (*[Predefined character classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#predef)*).

  - el `+` indica 1 o más caracteres

Comment: Quedo perfecto utilizando 

tokenizer.add("\\r?\\n", 1, "Salto de línea");
Ahora solo tengo un problema quiero que se detecte := (Dos puntos y simbolo igual) usando el regex pero no puedo lograrlo. Utilizo este regex en mi token

tokenizer.add("([:][=])", 13, "Simbolo de Asignacion");

Comment: @Dreox No es necesario usar una clase de caracteres, es suficiente con `"(:=)"` El problema es que ya tenés un patrón para "Dos puntos", y este debería tener prioridad (ponerlo antes) ... Para otras preguntas, deberías formularlas aparte. La idea del sitio es respetar 1 pregunta, 1 respuesta. – Mariano ahora mismo

Answer (score 0):

Agregar \n en tu expresión regular para el salto de linea.

```
((.*)\n*)
```

Los caracteres especiales utilizados en las expresiones regulares son:

```
Caracteres
\n — Salto de línea.
\r — Retorno de carro.
\s — Espacio en blanco.
\S — Cualquier carácter que no sea un espacio en blanco.
\t — Tabulador.
Grupos de caracteres
. — Cualquier carácter.
\w — Cualquier carácter alfanumérico.
\D — Letras.
A-Z — Letras mayúsculas.
a-z — Letras minúsculas.
\d — Dígitos.
0-9 — Dígitos.
\W — Cualquier carácter no alfanumérico.
Cuantificadores de cantidad
? — Una o ninguna vez.
* — Cero o más veces.
+ — Una o más veces.
{n} — Exactamente n veces.
{n,} — Por lo menos n veces.
{n,m} — Por lo menos n veces pero no más de m veces.
Límites
^ — Comienzo de línea
$ — Fin de una línea.
\b — Fin de palabra.
\B — No es fin de palabra.
\A — Principio de la cadena de entrada.
\z — Final de la cadena de entrada.
Intervales de caracteres
[abc] — Conjunto de caracteres.
[^abc] — Excepto conjunto de caracteres.
Operadores
| — OR
(abc) — Grupo de caracteres.
```